# Spring Integration - Unable to send the files with same name for second time

Tags: ftp, spring-integration

I could able to send a file Document.txt in local directory to remote directory , but couldnt able to FTP the same file ,if i delete the file in remote and try to send from local again .Poller is working fine ,since it picks up if i put different file in same folder .Can i have some insight on this ?

```
enter code here





    <!-- Inbound adapter channels for reading the local directory files in    processed folder -->
<file:inbound-channel-adapter id="inboundProcessed"
                                channel="processedChannel" 
                                filename-pattern="*.txt"
                                directory="$dina-communication.batch-{localDirectory}"
                                                                >
    <int:poller fixed-rate="10000" />
</file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:channel id="processedChannel"></int:channel>

        <!-- Outbound adapter channels for FTP the files in processed folder to remote directory -->    
    <int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter id="ftpProcessed"
                                channel="processedChannel" 
                                session-factory="ftpClientFactory"
                                remote-directory="$dina-communication.batch-{remoteDirectory}"
                                >

     <int-ftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
     <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">
        <property name="onSuccessExpression" value="payload.delete()" />
      </bean>
</int-ftp:request-handler-advice-chain>                     

    </int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please review the following and update your question according:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

The `<file:inbound-channel-adapter` uses `AcceptOnceFileListFilter` by default, which compares incoming files by their `hashCode` for the pathname:

```
/**
 * Computes a hash code for this abstract pathname.  Because equality of
 * abstract pathnames is inherently system-dependent, so is the computation
 * of their hash codes.  On UNIX systems, the hash code of an abstract
 * pathname is equal to the exclusive <em>or</em> of the hash code
 * of its pathname string and the decimal value
 * <code>1234321</code>.  On Microsoft Windows systems, the hash
 * code is equal to the exclusive <em>or</em> of the hash code of
 * its pathname string converted to lower case and the decimal
 * value <code>1234321</code>.  Locale is not taken into account on
 * lowercasing the pathname string.
 *
 * @return  A hash code for this abstract pathname
 */
public int hashCode() {
    return fs.hashCode(this);
}
```

Therefore when a new file comes with the same name it is ignored and can't go downstream your flow.

To overcome the problem you should use `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter`, which uses `lastModified` to compare if the files has been updated: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/files.html#file-reading

Comment: Sure ,i will give a try and keep posted !!

Comment: I actually tried using create another FTP client factory for outbound and it solved the issue ,since there are lot of FTP'e sessions in the project , tried that approach .